# Assigning many line colors based on group in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Suppose I have some code like the following, generating a lineplot with a considerable number of lines (example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27830084/4686625))

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

n = 1000
set.seed(123)

mat = matrix(rnorm(n^2), ncol=n)
cmat = apply(mat, 2, cumsum)
cmat = t(cmat)
rownames(cmat) = paste("trial", seq(n), sep="")
colnames(cmat) = paste("time", seq(n), sep="")

dat = as.data.frame(cmat)
dat$trial = rownames(dat)
mdat = melt(dat, id.vars="trial")
mdat$time = as.numeric(gsub("time", "", mdat$variable))


p = ggplot(mdat, aes(x=time, y=value, group=trial)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
    geom_line(size=0.2, alpha=0.1)
```

[image]

So here, "trial number" is my group producing all of these lines, and there are 1000 trials. 
Suppose I want to "group my grouping variable" now - that is, I want to see the exact same lines in this plot, but I want the first 500 trial lines to be one color and the next 500 trial lines to be another. How can I do this with ggplot? I've been poking around for some time and I can't figure out how to manually set the colors per group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution will be to create a new column with the index of the trial number and then using an `ifelse` condition, you can set different group based on the trial number and pass the grouping variable as `color` in `aes` such as:

```r
mdat %>% mutate(Trial = as.numeric(sub("trial","",trial))) %>%
  mutate(Group = ifelse(Trial < 51,"A","B")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=time, y=value, group=trial, color = Group)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
  geom_line(size=0.2, alpha=0.8)
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

---

NB: I only use `n = 100` to get smallest dataframe.

Comment: Oh.. there's a `color` in `aes` I've never used... geez. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ;). A lot of aesthetic parameters can be pass into `aes`. You will find a lot of example on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Add a variable splitting the data into two groups, then add use it to color the lines in ggplot

```
dat = as.data.frame(cmat)
dat$trial = rownames(dat)
dat$group = rep(c("a","b"), each = n/2)
mdat = melt(dat, id.vars=c("trial", "group"))
mdat$time = as.numeric(gsub("time", "", mdat$variable))


p = ggplot(mdat, aes(x=time, y=value, group=trial, color = group)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
  geom_line(size=0.2, alpha=0.1)
```